# Java JFrame components

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a simple 500x500 applet with a button, 2-label, and textfield. The applet opens up but it is just blank no components are displaying nor will the color change. Not sure what is happening or what I'm missing exactly.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Greeting {
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private JLabel label1;
private JTextField textbox1;
private JButton button1;
private JLabel label2;

public Greeting(){
    gui();

}

    public void gui(){
        frame = new JFrame("Greeting");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        label1 = new JLabel ("Please enter your name");
        textbox1 = new JTextField(20);
        button1 = new JButton ("Greet");

        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(textbox1);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Greeting();

    }

}
```

Comment: @Heyyou No they don't the op is building the UI in an instance of gui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are planning on displaying `frame` with all the components, then move the `frame.setVisible(true)` line to the end of the method:

```
public void gui() {
    ...
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This allows for all the components to be added to the `JFrame` before it is displayed on the screen.